# Python3 in DockerFile running ubuntu::latest

Tags: python, docker

I am trying to upgrade from running my script in Python 2.7 to Python 3.5. It is a simple Flask admin script running inside a docker container.

DockerFile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y python-pip python3.5-dev build-essential libpq-dev

....

CMD ["/usr/bin/python", "app.py"]
```

This runs it in python 2.7. I tried updating to

```
CMD ["/usr/bin/python3", "parcelnotifer.py"]
```

but this results in an error

> Cannot start service dev: oci runtime error: exec: "/usr/bin/python3": stat /usr/bin/python3: no such file or directory

If I docker exec into the container when it is running on 2.7 I can use the command python3 so Python3 is definitely installed I am just not sure how to force the script to run in Python3

Answer (score 4):

You can first check where Python is getting installed with `which python3` and then put that path into your `CMD` command.

Comment: Thank you. The path is /usr/bin/python3 which I had already tried but I must have had a typo as it now works. However, it appears the packages for example splinter, flask which were installed via PIP are not working on Python 3.

Comment: @19421608, this is OK if you've installed them for Python2 only. You should install them for Python3 as well, but now with `pip3`, not `pip`.

Comment: It is saying `/bin/sh: 1: pip-3: not found` (same happens when I remove the dash and use just pip3) when I run docker-compose. I tried to install pip3 but also got an error: ': Unable to locate package python-pip3'

Comment: @19421608, you can get `pip3` for 3.x by installing the package `python3-pip`